# Different results on databricks and Google Colab while using pyspark transformation

Tags: python, pandas, apache-spark, pyspark, databricks

I was trying to do a data transformation but I found a different result while using pyspark in databricks and google colab.
I am basically converting a pysaprk dataframe from long form to wide form. In the manner below.

here is my code snippet.

```
from pyspark.sql.types import DoubleType
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('abc').getOrCreate()
df = spark.createDataFrame([1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0,5.0,6.0,7.0,8.0,9.0], DoubleType()).toDF("Number")
df.show()
>>
+------+
|Number|
+------+
|   1.0|
|   2.0|
|   3.0|
|   4.0|
|   5.0|
|   6.0|
|   7.0|
|   8.0|
|   9.0|
+------+

from pyspark.sql import functions as F, Window
from math import sqrt
c = int(sqrt(df.count())) #this gives 3
rnum = F.row_number().over(Window.orderBy(F.lit(1)))

out = (df.withColumn("Rnum",((rnum-1)%c).cast("Integer"))
 .withColumn("idx",F.row_number().over(Window.partitionBy("Rnum").orderBy("Rnum")))
.groupby("Rnum").pivot("idx").agg(F.first("Number")))
```

The output of out.show in colab looks like this. Which is the desired output I need.
https://colab.research.google.com/drive/10Yuggohq3MmpckWgcJrc5w1Q8vu5jSEh#scrollTo=JxnQk51nEkJd

```
+----+---+---+---+
|Rnum|  1|  2|  3|
+----+---+---+---+
|   0|1.0|4.0|7.0|
|   1|2.0|5.0|8.0|
|   2|3.0|6.0|9.0|
+----+---+---+---+
```

While in databricks where I am running the code on a production cluster (64 cores | 224GB | DBR 7.0 | Spark 3.0.0) the output is different every time I run the transformation code. For eg. one of the instance the code output for out.show() is:

```
+----+---+---+---+
|Rnum|  1|  2|  3|
+----+---+---+---+
|   0|3.0|7.0|1.0|
|   1|4.0|2.0|5.0|
|   2|8.0|6.0|9.0|
+----+---+---+---+
```

How can I make sure that consistent output is shown in databricks every time that the transformation is done.

Comment: Spark dataframes are unordered. There is no guarantee that the row number is sequential, especially when there is a large number of partitions, e.g. in your databricks cluster.

Comment: Any way this problem can be resolved? @mck

Comment: @anky can you have a look at this and give some ideas how to make sure this does not happen?